# How to know the value of indices using find function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, find, indices

I have a 4096x2 matrix called `datos1`. I'm trying to plot from its highest value with `[valor_maximo, canal_maximo]=max(datos1(:,2));` to a percentage given (5% of the highest value) with

```
conteomin=ceil(valor_maximo*0.05);
[canal_minimo, valor_minimo]=find(datos1(:,2) == conteomin);
```

My question is, now that I have the indices in both cases, how do I know the values in the `find` function?

At the moment, `[canal_minimo, valor_minimo]=...`returns the value for `canal_minimo` but for `valor_minimo` only the number of incidences to each row and not the actual value in the matrix; i.e. `canal_minimo=3558 valor_minimo=1`,  instead of equal to `conteomin`.

```
fileID=fopen(uigetfile('*.txt', 'Seleccione el archivo'));
[archivo,~,~,~]=fopen(fileID(1));
datos1=dlmread(archivo,' ',10,0);
fclose(fileID);
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',datos1);

[valor_maximo, canal_maximo]=max(datos1(:,2));
conteomin=ceil(valor_maximo*0.05);
[canal_minimo, valor_minimo]=find(datos1(:,2) == conteomin);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `find` returns indices to the non-zero values of `datos1(:,2) == conteomin`. That is, it finds the indices where `datos1(:,2)` is exactly equal to `conteomin`. Consequently, the value at those locations is `conteomin`. Do note that `==` for floating-point values is dangerous, it is likely that your matrix doesn't contain any elements with exactly that value.

Comment: I see, the main issue is with the `find` function. For example the following:
`[valor_maximo, canal_maximo] = [10000 1109]`
`[valor_minimo, canal_minimo]=[1 3000]`

The 5% of 10000 is 500. Instead it is always showng 1.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone, I was not realizing that `find` returns a `1` when it is true, so the value was already stored on another variable.

How do I assign the answer to close the question?

Comment: I posted my comments as a community-wiki answer. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark underneath the vote arrows on the left of the question. You might be interested in taking the [tour], where it is explained how Stack Overflow works. Finally: if you want another (one) specific user to see your comment, use `@<username>` to notify them; the post-owner will always be notified. Notifying me thus can be done with `@Adriaan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[row,col]=find(LogicalExpression)` gives the row/column indices for each element adhering to the `LogicalExpression`. So in your case: everywhere where an element of the second column of `datos1` equals the scalar value `conteomin` it will register as true, and the `canal_minimo` will have the row number; and the `valor_minimo` is obviously one, since it's the column number of a column vector, clear as day 1 of course. `[row,col,val]=find()` gives the value in the third output, but you don't need that, given that you compare to a hard number (which is a bad idea as [@CrisLuengo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942220/how-to-know-the-value-of-indices-using-find-function-in-matlab#comment92792996_52942220)). This because `val` will be equal to `conteomin`, *since that's what you asked for*. It's of no use (in this case) outputting it explicitly.